# Date Format Conversion in PHP 5.1.2

Tags: php, cakephp

1.2 and need to convert a date from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`
For example if the date is in format `07/08/2014`, it should appear as `2014-08-07`

How can this be done? I know `strtotime` returns unix timestamp but it doesn't seem to work with dates with Slashes (/) in it. SInce I'm using 5.1, a lot of `DateTime` functions are not supported in it.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**DateTime**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class, `strtotime` function would create issue when date less then **1901** with PHP 5.3.0

Try this way

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "07/08/2014");
$new_date_format = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass a correct format with `-`(date string separation with dash) in `date()` try

```
$d = str_replace('/', '-','07/08/2014');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d)); //2014-08-07
```

with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
$objDateTime = new DateTime($d);
echo $objDateTime->format('Y-m-d'); //2014-08-07
```

Comment: FYI, no need to convert `07/08/2014` into `07-08-2014` if you are using `DateTime` class, `/` and `-` both formats are supported.

Comment: @Girish yeah i know but better to use date in correct format

Answer (score -1):

By using `date()` function yuo can try this

```
echo date('Y-d-m',strtotime('07/08/2014'));
```

Check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))`

Where `$date` is in any format that you want to convert to `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Answer (score -1):

**Method : 1** [demo](https://eval.in/176443)

```
$date1 = "07/08/2014";
$arr = explode("/", $date1);

$date2 = $arr[2]."-".$arr[1]."-".$arr[0];
echo $date2;
```

**Method : 2**   [demo](https://eval.in/176440)

```
$date1 = "07/08/2014";
list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $date1);

$date2 = $year."-".$month."-".$day;
echo $date2;
```

**Method 3 :** with `strtotime` [Demo](https://eval.in/176445)

```
$date1 = "07/08/2014";
$date1 = str_replace("/", "-", $date1);
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
echo $date2;
```